# Win XP MTP drivers

Tags: windows-xp, android, mtp

I have a Lenovo vibe k5 note(a7020a48) and a k5 plus(a6020a40). I want to transfer files from the phones to my old pc which runs XP. I downloaded MTP drivers for XP. My k5 note works fine and I can transfer data to and fro, but my k5 plus does not show up
 It shows up as unknown device and sometimes it shows USB device not working.

I downloaded the drivers from softpedia.

Comment: I would download and intsall this one from Microsoft....https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=19153

Comment: I have done that as well. With hindsight it's probably the phone. Tried with 3 other phones, they work fine. It's the k5 plus that's having issues.

Comment: See if anything on this page helps....https://gsmusbdriver.com/lenovo-k5-note

Comment: A comment for up-dating the [URL given by @Moab](/questions/1331374/win-xp-mtp-drivers#comment1988902_1331374): The URL at microsoft.com does not work anymore, but download is still [possible from archive.org](http://web.archive.org/web/20200804141409/www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19153).